# Akka.Net Remoting Configuration + Association questions

Tags: akka.net

we just upgraded Akka.Net to 1.1.3 from 1.0.7 and noticed that remoting HOCON had a few new properties such that the following works on Azure, but doesn't on private dedicated servers (say a GoDaddy box):

```
akka {
     actor { provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote"" }
     remote {
          helios.tcp {
                                    port = 0
                                    hostname = 0.0.0.0
                                    dns-use-ipv6 = false
                                    public-hostname = localhost
                                    enforce-ip-family = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

And the following works well on dedicated servers, but not on Azure:

```
akka {
                            actor {
                                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                            }
                            remote {
                                helios.tcp {
                                    port = 0
                                    hostname = 0.0.0.0
                                    dns-use-ipv6 = false
                                    public-hostname = localhost 
                                    enforce-ip-family = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

From the documentation in the change logs that I found, it appears that enforce-ip-family is a setting which when set to TRUE would allow forcing a client to use IPv6 by setting dns-use-ipv6 to true.

Is this a correct interpretation on my part? Is there some documentation regarding these settings that we could read?

Also, let's say that I wanted to use IPv6 on Azure, what would the server configuration be? Is this even something that I could control?

I also noticed something with the new version that I hadn't noticed before, overnight, I started getting these exceptions:

> Tried to associate with unreachable remote address
>   [akka.tcp://TestActorSystem@localhost:51675]. Address is now gated for
>   5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead
>   letters. Reason: [No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.

We hadn't seen these errors before and it really doesn't look like there's a specific reason on this before the first one started. Has anyone else experienced this? Could any one shed some light on what I could do to gracefully resolve this situation? A critical piece of functionality stopped working because of this issue and we're trying to figure out how to best address it.

Please pardon my lack of expertise on Akka 1.1.3 but I think I had it all figured out until I inadvertently upgraded the nuget package and had a rude awakening :)

Thank You,
Anup